# SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition Standalone Installer

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to automate the creation of QA environments using Chef.  One of the components I need is SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition.

Currently I get an ISO through MSDN.  However, I want a single EXE that I can download and install via command line.  I can't seem to find one.

My alternative approach will be to extract the ISO, zip up the contents, make them available for download on my network, download the zip, extract the zip, and run the setup.exe.  I'd like to avoid all of that if I can.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

See Scott Hanselman's direct download links:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx